# How do I get indents in a Julia docstring?

Tags: loops, julia, indentation, docstring

I want to include a loop in a Julia docstring, yet the indent does not show up when I try what looks like the obvious way to do it.

```
"""
Function: dave

Arguments

  x: first number

  y: second number

Returns

  interaction_sum: x + y + xy

Examples

#=

for i in 1:5

    println(dave(i, i)) # 3, 8, 15, 24, 35

end

=#

"""
```

However, when I throw the question mark in front of my function to get the documentation, the indent for the loop isn't there.

```
Function: dave
Arguments
x: first number
y: second number
Returns 
interaction_sum: x + y + xy
Examples
#=
for i in 1:5
println(dave(i, i)) # 3, 8, 15, 24, 35
end
=#
```

I have no such issue in Python. How do I get those tabs to show up in Julia?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [Documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/documentation/) section for more details on how to format the doc string.

````
julia> """
           dave

       # Arguments

         x: first number

         y: second number

       # Returns

         interaction_sum: x + y + xy

       # Examples

       ```
       for i in 1:5

           println(dave(i, i)) # 3, 8, 15, 24, 35

       end

       ```
       """
       function dave() end
````

```
help?> dave
search: dave code_native @code_native readavailable

  dave

  Arguments
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  x: first number

  y: second number

  Returns
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  interaction_sum: x + y + xy

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  for i in 1:5
  
      println(dave(i, i)) # 3, 8, 15, 24, 35
  
  end
```

Comment: There are some formatting issues in the code you posted that prevent it from being copied verbatim without editing the indents. If you tidy that, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Actually, one can directly copy the code and paste it into the Julia REPL. The indents will be handled automatically ;)